# Reading text into a linked list using structs in C

Tags: c, list, text, input, struct

I'm attempting to create a linked list using a struct from a txt file. Initially, I'm testing it with a txt file with only one line of information. This code compiles correctly, however when I run it, it returns "Line...didn't scan properly". As an aside, if I remove the if statement that returns such a value I get complete gibberish. I have no clue why the line isn't being scanned correctly, however I feel as though it may having something to do with the hyphen/plus sign in two of the terms that I tried to scan as strings. Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

This is the txt file:

```
1 20959U 90103A   14091.58762725 -.00000015  00000-0  00000+0 0  3197
```

This is the tester.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct noradData {
    // line one
    int                lineNum;
    char             * satNum;
    char             * intDesig;
    float              epoch;
    float              firstTimeDeriv;
    char             * secondTimeDeriv;
    char             * drag;
    int                zero;
    int                set;
    struct noradData * next;
} Data; 

Data * first = NULL, * last = NULL;

int main() {
    char line[80], secondTimeDeriv[7], drag[7], satNum[6], intDesig[6];
    int lineNum, zero, set; 
    float epoch, firstTimeDeriv;

    FILE * fIn;
    Data * node;

    fIn = fopen("data1.txt", "r");
    if (fIn == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fIn) != NULL) {
        // Check line for various problems (too short, too long).
        if (line[0] == '\0') {
            printf ("Line too short\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (line[strlen (line)-1] != '\n') {
            printf ("Line starting with '%s' is too long\n", line);
            return 1;
        }

        line[strlen (line)-1] = '\0';

        // Scan the individual fields.

        if (scanf("%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d", &lineNum, satNum, intDesig, 
                &epoch, &firstTimeDeriv, secondTimeDeriv, drag, &zero, &set) 
                != 9) {
            printf ("Line '%s' didn't scan properly\n", line);
            return 1;
        }

        node = malloc(sizeof(Data));
        if (node == NULL) {
            printf ("Ran out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }

        node->lineNum = lineNum;
        node->satNum = strdup(satNum);
        node->intDesig = strdup (intDesig);
        node->epoch = epoch;
        node->firstTimeDeriv = firstTimeDeriv;
        node->secondTimeDeriv = strdup(secondTimeDeriv);
        node->drag = strdup(drag);
        node->zero = zero;
        node->set = set;
        node->next = NULL;

        if (first != NULL) {
            last->next = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else {
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }
    }
    fclose (fIn);
    node = first;
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d", node->lineNum, node->satNum, 
            node->intDesig, node->epoch, node->firstTimeDeriv, 
            node->secondTimeDeriv, node->drag, node->zero, node->set);
        node = node->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you want `sscanf(line, "%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d",
          &lineNum, satNum, intDesig, &epoch,
          &firstTimeDeriv, secondTimeDeriv, //&power1,
     drag, &zero, &set)` instead of `scanf("%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d",
          &lineNum, satNum, intDesig, &epoch,
          &firstTimeDeriv, secondTimeDeriv, //&power1,
     drag, &zero, &set)`?

Comment: hey, thanks for trying to help out. I got this error when i tried changing it to "sscanf": tester.c:87:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘sscanf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
               &set) != 9){
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from tester.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (sscanf, (const char *__restrict __s,
            ^
Any suggestions? Much appreciated!

Comment: Odd. Are you sure you used `sscanf(line, "%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d", &lineNum, satNum, intDesig, &epoch, &firstTimeDeriv, secondTimeDeriv, drag, &zero, &set)` (Did you forget the first argument `line`)?

Comment: Right now you don't know where in the line this is failing. Work incrementally. sscanf(line, "%d", &lineNum), if that works add another item. You could maybe pull this out into a little program scanning a hard-coded string. As a general approach I always work in very small tested increments.

Comment: @CoolGuy: nailed it. Forgot the "line" argument. I changed the if statement to:
       if(sscanf(line, "%d %s %s %f %f %s %s %d %d",
              &lineNum, satNum, intDesig, &epoch,
              &firstTimeDeriv, secondTimeDeriv,
       drag, &zero, &set) == 0){
            printf ("Line '%s' didn't scan properly\n", line);
            return 1;
        }
and now it returns: 1 20959U 90103A 14091.587891 -0.000000 00000-0 00000+0 0 31971 20959U 90103A 14091.587891 -0.000000 00000-0 00000+0 0 3197

can't figure out why it's returning the line twice...

you rock thank you!

Comment: @FarisSbahi `==0` should be `!=9`. When did I tell you to change that? And I don't know why it is printing everything twice. Could you post the updated code somewhere?

Comment: @djna thank you for the suggestion, I have a lot of bad programming habits currently... will take this into note

Comment: @CoolGuy I changed it because it wasn't functioning properly, if I change it back i'll get the return "Line...didn't scan properly".

Updated code: http://collabedit.com/bc2ak

Comment: It also appears you forgot to leave `+1` space in strings like `satNum[6]`. It looks like satnum is `20959U` or `90103A` both with `6` chars so `satNum[7]` is the minimum required.  Check the rest -- remember space for the `null-terminator` otherwise all your strings are not null-terminated and you are experiencing undefined behavior when you call any string function expecting them to be terminated. Specifically, it will drive `strdup` nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change size of character arrays satnum and intdDesig to 7
that is satnum[7] and intDesig[7]. You want to store 6 characters in these leave last index for null value.

```
if (line[strlen (line)-1] != '\n') {
        printf ("Line starting with '%s' is too long\n", line);
        return 1;
    }
```

This if statement instead of line[strlen(line)-1]!='\n' put this-

```
line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n'
```

and statement goes like this

```
    if (line[strlen (line)-1]=='\n') {
        printf ("Line starting with '%s' is too long\n", line);
        return 1;
    }
```

And remove this line

```
line[strlen (line)-1] = '\0';
```

Then line will not be returned twice .